# tricky sql - select data between dates and... complete missing dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite database. Simple table:

```
MyTable - columns: Date, Value
```

I want to selects records for given range of dates. And until now it's very simple, but.... if for some dates within the given range there are no records, I would like to get the rows like "2014-01-01", "0" (given date only as an example, I would like to have this "empty" record for each date which is missing in the given range).

Ex. expected result:

```
2013-12-31, 10
2014-01-01, 0
2014-01-02, 0
2014-01-03,22
```

assuming the given range was 2013-12-31 - 2014-01-03 and the records for 1st and 2nd January were missing.

Thus the question is how to complete records for missing date in the result query. Any chance to do it in SQL and not in java?

Answer (score 1):

If this were me, I'd create a date table in Excel (just go from 1900 to 2100 or something like that) and increment day by day. Then you could do something like

```
SELECT dl.date, CASE WHEN t.value IS NOT NULL THEN t.value ELSE 0 END AS value 
FROM {date_lookup_table} AS dl 
LEFT OUTER JOIN {your_table} as t 
ON dl.date = t.date WHERE dl.date 
BETWEEN {start} AND {end}
```

Obviously the bracketed terms would have to change based on what you need.

Can you fill in the data? Yeah, I'm sure you can. But using a date table is way simpler, and it's the kind of thing you'll end up using again and again (if it were me, I'd create that date lookup table with, for example, Day of the Week, Month, Year, Day, and the Date all pre-populated... this can be done easily in Excel)

Comment: Excel is not a solution in my case, but the idea is quite interesting. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer suggests, you can accomplish this with joins from a utility table full of dates. At the end of this post is sample SQL to build such a table conveniently. You could then base your query on the utility table, and LEFT JOIN against your actual data. This will present rows even for gaps in data:

```
SELECT d.day, SUM(m.value) AS value_sum
FROM utility_day d
LEFT JOIN mytable m ON d.day = m.`date`
WHERE d.day BETWEEN "2013-12-31" AND "2014-01-03"
GROUP BY d.day;
```

Here's an [SQLFiddle to demonstrate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62852/2/0).

Sample utility_day Table Creation:

```
# Create utility_day table.

CREATE TABLE `utility_day` (
  `day` date default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`day`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT IGNORE utility_day (day)
SELECT DATE_ADD("2000-01-01", INTERVAL ones.num + tens.num + hundreds.num + thousands.num DAY) AS day
FROM
(
SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
SELECT 1 num UNION ALL
SELECT 2 num UNION ALL
SELECT 3 num UNION ALL
SELECT 4 num UNION ALL
SELECT 5 num UNION ALL
SELECT 6 num UNION ALL
SELECT 7 num UNION ALL
SELECT 8 num UNION ALL
SELECT 9 num
) ones
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
SELECT 10 num UNION ALL
SELECT 20 num UNION ALL
SELECT 30 num UNION ALL
SELECT 40 num UNION ALL
SELECT 50 num UNION ALL
SELECT 60 num UNION ALL
SELECT 70 num UNION ALL
SELECT 80 num UNION ALL
SELECT 90 num
) tens
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
SELECT 100 num UNION ALL
SELECT 200 num UNION ALL
SELECT 300 num UNION ALL
SELECT 400 num UNION ALL
SELECT 500 num UNION ALL
SELECT 600 num UNION ALL
SELECT 700 num UNION ALL
SELECT 800 num UNION ALL
SELECT 900 num
) hundreds
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT 0 num UNION ALL
SELECT 1000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 2000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 3000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 4000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 5000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 6000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 7000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 8000 num UNION ALL
SELECT 9000 num
) thousands
WHERE DATE_ADD("2000-01-01", INTERVAL ones.num + tens.num + hundreds.num + thousands.num DAY) < "2030-01-01";
```

Comment: It's quite interesting idea, although I have impression it would be easier to process it in java, then create another huge table. I was simply wondering if perhaps there is unknown for me trick in SQL giving the possibility to complete the missing dates but basing on the answers probably something like this doesn't exist in SQL. Thank you for help.